# VueJS router handle all request

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I encounter an error, VueJS router supports all paths even those where one or more components have not been linked

```
const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
  { path: '/home', redirect: '/' },
  { path: '/reset-password' },
  { path: '/create', name: 'Create', component: CreateInnovation },
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'stage-table', component: Dashboard }
];

export const createRouter = () => {
  const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    // @ts-ignore
    base: __dirname,
    routes
  })

  return router
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Jérémy

Comment: If after you've defined your paths, you include: `{ path: '*', redirect: '/404' },`, then create a 404 component at that path, then any undefined route will land on your 404 page.

Comment: Are you using Vue 2, or Vue 3? The answer is different depending on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new route, with a custom param regexp to catch all routes which haven't been defined. You'll also need to create a `NotFound` component to be your 404 view.

#### Vue 3

```js
const routes: RouteConfig[] = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
  { path: '/home', redirect: '/' },
  { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFound },
];
```

#### Vue 2

```js
export const new Router({
  routes: [
    ...
    {
      path: '*',
      name: '404',
      component: () => import('./views/404.vue'),
    },
  ]
});
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for yours responses, my Vue version is 2.6.12.

My need is for vue-router to pass routes that are not set during initialization.

Comment: Using `*` will pass all routes that aren't otherwise defined, is that not what you mean?

Comment: Hi,

I don't want any undeclared route taken into account by vue-router.

Comment: So where do you want undeclared routes to navigate to?